# What fields are shown in the object manager (Activities)?

Tags: tooling-api, activities, object-manager

If I query fields by using:

```
task_fields = pd.DataFrame(sf.query(
    "SELECT QualifiedApiName, Label FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.Label IN ('Task')")[
                            'records'])
```

Then I get for example the Recurrence Activity Field. Which is not visible in object manager. How can I filter on fields that are visible in the object manager?

Comment: Please note `Task` and `Event` are both types of `Activity`, and they share some fields, potentially complicating this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EntityParticle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entityparticle.htm) would be the best source for this for objects you'll typically interact with:

> **Represents each element of a field that can be presented in a user
> interface.** Contrast EntityParticle with FieldDefinition, which
> represents each element of a field defined in the Metadata API.

And reference `IsLayoutable`

> If true, the field can be assigned to a layout.

As such, you can do the following:

```
SELECT QualifiedApiName, 
(SELECT IsLayoutable FROM Particles) 
FROM FieldDefinition 
WHERE EntityDefinition.Label = 'Task' ORDER BY QualifiedApiName ASC
```

Where `IsLayoutable = true` *should* highlight the fields that are displayed in the UI (Setup).

---

*Notes*

- That will return available fields for both *Activity* & *Task* that are presented separately in the Object Manager
- I said "*should*" - as there's a small amount of exceptions across several objects. For Task, this is

  - `Email`
  - `Phone`
- I also said "*objects you typically interact with*" as there are some objects that display in `Object Manager` that are not layoutable so all fields would be `false` even though fields display. I found a couple examples in my dev org

  - [AgentWork](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_agentwork.htm)
  - [ElectronicMediaGroup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_electronicmediagroup.htm)
  - [UserServicePresence](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userservicepresence.htm).
  - In these cases, there appears to be other rules related to other attributes on the `EntityParticle` record that dictate what fields show: `IsCalculated = false` && `IsIdLookup = false`.

---

Since you're using simple-salesforce and doing a sub-query - I'd suggest flattening the data before passing it to pandas.

```python
data = sf.query("SELECT QualifiedApiName, (SELECT IsLayoutable FROM Particles) FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.Label = 'Task' ORDER BY QualifiedApiName ASC")

records = [];
for rec in data['records']:
    if(rec['Particles'] is not None):
        records.append(dict(QualifiedApiName=rec['QualifiedApiName'], isLayoutable=rec['Particles']['records'][0]['IsLayoutable']))
    else:
        records.append(dict(QualifiedApiName=rec['QualifiedApiName'], isLayoutable=False))

print(pd.DataFrame(records))
```

That should print

|  | QualifiedApiName | IsLayoutable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AccountId | False |
| 1 | ActivityDate | True |
| 2 | CallDisposition | True |
| 3 | ... | ... |

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate reply. I see that there's no evident way to just get the fields shown in the object manager. However for me this is "close enough". As it is not exactly the same I think showing the boolean value of "IsLayoutable" next to all fields available for the tooling API is the best. However if I use your exact query string and export it to csv then I don't get just the "IsLayoutable" boolean but an orderedDict with all properties of particles. I will accept it as an answer if you could show how to only get the boolean value of "IsLayoutable"

Comment: How exactly are you executing that query that you get that result? I presume, based on the example you shared in the question it's simple salesforce (python)?

Comment: Hi Kris, it is simple_salesforce. I don't know how to share the code decently in a comment but this is what I use: pd.DataFrame(sf.query("SELECT QualifiedApiName, Label, DataType, Description, IsNillable, (SELECT IsLayoutable FROM Particles) FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.Label = 'Task' ")['records']).

Comment: You'll just want to pull the sub-query records out before assigning it to the dataframe (see relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860134/parent-child-relationship-query-in-simple-salesforce-python-extracting-from-ord)). Updated answer to show how I did it.

Comment: Thanks for the very well structured answer.